# RequireJS loads modules in wrong order even if dependencies are specified

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the following RequireJS configuration:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    },
    shim: {
        angular: ['jquery']
    }
});
```

After this, I am loading the `app` module:

```
require(['app'], function (app) {

});
```

I have the according `app.js` as follows:

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
    console.log(angular); //Prints out undefined
});
```

I have `angular.js` and `jquery.js` located under my `lib` directory in my site's root.

In fact, they are being loaded just fine, the problem is the loading order.

If I check my HTML, they are being loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="app" src="lib/../app.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="jquery" src="lib/jquery.js">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async="" data-requirecontext="_" data-requiremodule="angular" src="lib/angular.js">
```

As you can see, my `app` module is being loaded before `angular` **and** `jquery`.

I already specified that `app` module has a dependency on `angular`, what do I have to do so RequireJS can load my modules in the right order?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Vishwanath Nope, zero errors.